# Wordpress : AFC filter out past dates on a repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Currently have a list of events in a table I have managed to get them to sort via date the closest date first however I would like past dates to get filtered out and not display. At the minute I am trying to use a if statement to check if the date is more then or equal to the current date but it is not working getting no errors

```
    $repeater = get_field('dates');
            $currentdate  = date('Ymd');
            echo $currentdate;

            foreach( $repeater as $key => $row )
            {

                $column_id[ $key ] = $row['date'];}

             array_multisort( $column_id, SORT_ASC, $repeater );
             foreach( $repeater as $row ) :

                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $row['date']);

                    ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php if ($date >= $currentdate) { echo $date->format('d') ;}?><?php  endforeach;?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your code there is a bracket ( missing after if.

```
 <?php if $date >= $currentdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$repeater = get_field('dates');
$currentdate  = date('Ymd'); 
foreach($repeater as $dates) {
    $date = $dates['date'];
    $date = date('Ymd', strtotime($date));
    if(strtotime($date) >= strtotime($currentdate)) {
        echo 'it is working';   
    }
}
?>
```

Let me know if it works